# Make a loop stop on variable being false

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to make a discord bot that says a message every 5 seconds when a condition or command is executed, and stop that loop when another one is executed. I have simple code and I'm not sure why its not working, I have just make it log to console for testing right now.

I have tried `while loop` and `for loop`, `setinterval` and they just won't stop even when I set the var to false.

```
var c = 0;

if (message.content == prefix + 'test') {
    message.delete();
    c = 1;
    while (c = 1) {
        setInterval(function () {
            console.log(c);
        }, 5000)
    }
}

if (message.content == prefix + 'stoptest') {       
    message.delete();
     c = 2;
}


if (message.content == prefix + 'check') {       
    message.delete();
    console.log(c);
}
```

I'm confused why when I do the stoptest command and set the var c to 2 it still continues to log in console saying that c = 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this is not working is because the while loop is happening synchronously, meaning the code following it will never get a change to execute as the while loop will never actually exit.

If you simply want to keep posting messages until a certain event fires, a loop is not necessary. Instead, you can try:

```
var interval;

if (message.content == prefix + 'test') {
    interval = setInterval(function () {
        // Post your messages to Discord here
    }, 5000)
}

if (message.content == prefix + 'stoptest' && interval) {
    clearInterval(interval);
}
```

Here, we set an interval that starts when the message content is `prefix + 'test'`, and we clear that interval whenever the content is `prefix + 'stoptest'`. This will keep your code asynchronous, meaning the rest of your code will get a chance to execute once the interval has been started.

Answer (score 6):

when you write :

```
while (c = 1) {
   setInterval(function () {
      console.log(c);
   }, 5000)
}
```

- `c = 1` is not a condition, check operator in JS `==`
- `setInterval()` is already designed to call something indefinitely so don't nest it in a while loop

if you want to write a loop that can be stopped :

```
let flag = true;

while(flag) {
  //do something
  if(anythingYouChooseHappens) {
    flag = false; // that stops the loop
    // or if don't want to use a variable you can just write `break` in this closure
  }
}
```

I think while loop is not the best solution here so you can start with :

```
let myInterval;

myInterval = setInterval(function() {
    console.log(c);
    if(anythingYouChooseHappens) {
        clearInterval(myInterval); //stop the 'loop'
    }
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var a;
if(message.content == prefix + 'ckeck'){
a = setInterval(()=>{
    if(message.content, == prefix + 'stop'){
        clearInterval(a);
    }
},5000);
```